# Calculus train question

Tags: calculus, optimization, problem-solving

A train leaves the station at $10:00$ *am* and travels due south at a speed of $60km/h$. Another train has been heading due west at $45km/h$ and reaches the same station at $11:00$ *am*. At what time were the two trains the closest together?  (Preferably to be solved using derivatives!)

Comment: There is an edit button below the question.

Comment: I think I have to make 2 functions for the 2 trains and then use the distance formula to solve for the answer, I am just not sure how to construct the formulas for both trains.

Comment: Draw a right triangle. Label the legs $x,y$, you know rate of change of $x,y$ wrt to time and length of total $y$. Calculate hypotenuse ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that you want the length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle with vertical leg (the southern bound train) of length of $\;60x\;$, and a horizontal leg (the other train) of length $\;45(1-x)\;$ , with $\;x\,$= time ellapsed since $\;10:00\;$ , so the wanted hypotenuse's length (squared) is

$$f(x)=3,600 x^2+2,025(1-x)^2=5,625x^2-4,050 x+2,025=0\implies$$

$$f'(x)=11,250x-4,050=0\implies x=\frac{4,050}{11,250}=\frac25\implies$$

At $\;10:00 + 24'=10:24\;$ the distance was minimal, and this was

$$\sqrt{f\left(\frac25\right)}\approx36.12 \;kms.$$

Comment: Just a pedantic little correction but please don't write $kms$, as it means kilometer second. Just plain $km$ would do.

Comment: @Deepak For me, kms. = kilometers, and I've no idea what "kilometer second" can possibly mean. If it meants "kilometer per second" then I'd write it km/s ., just line m/h measn "miles per hour", say.

Comment: There is no separate plural form for units. For reference you may consult this (third from the top): http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html Writing something like $kms$ engenders ambiguity, since a derived unit such as kilometer (times) second  is conceivable. I can only think of a contrived example where this unit might be used (example: a rental charge on a vehicle that takes into account both time and distance) but since you can have units like $Ns$ (Newton second) for impulse, usage like this shouldn't be discounted.